# How to find and update specific record in js datatables

Tags: javascript, html, datatables

I need to loop through `datatable`, find a record with specyfic id, and the update it (only this one).

```
<table id="data_tables">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td value="id">id_value</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Surname</td>
    <tr>      
</thead>
<tbody>
    <!-- Datarow 1 -->
    <tr>
        <td value="1">1</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Wayne</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Datarow 2 -->      
    <tr>
        <td value="2">2</td>
        <td>Clark</td>
        <td>Kent</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Datarow 3 -->      
    <tr>
        <td value="3">3</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Romero</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And the js code. It must be datatble based becouse standard looping will not work with datatable paging (or at least it didn't work form me).

```
    var counter = 0; //to tell me if rows numer is fine

    var table = $('#data_tables').DataTable(); //to grab anchor to datatable again

    //datatable way
    table.rows().every( function () {
        counter = counter + 1;
        //I don't know how to adress current row in a loop in datatable api     
        if(current_row.value_or_content == 10){

          current_row[1].value = 'New Name';
          current_row[1].value = 'New Surname';

        }

    } );

    alert(counter); //that is why I know that looping works ok
    table.draw(); //to keep filters ok
```

This is how I tried, but anyway would be good. Propably even better without looping (speed issues if the is LOTS of data in datatable?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could pass additional parameters in the function callback for the `rows().every()` api. Use the `rowIdx` to monitor and check the index of the row of the table and then delete it.

If you want to access the row's data, you can use `this.data()`. It will return an array containing the row's data. For example, if the current row is the first one, the returned data should be:

```
[
"1",
"John",
"Wayne"
]
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  const table = $('#data_tables').DataTable(); //to grab anchor to datatable again

  //datatable way
  table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    // The checks the id of the current row
    if (this.data()[0] === "1") {

      console.log(`This is row number ${rowIdx+1}`);
      console.log(`This is this row's data:`);
      console.log(this.data());
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<table id="data_tables" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th value="id">id_value</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Surname</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <!-- Datarow 1 -->
    <tr>
      <td value="1">1</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Wayne</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Datarow 2 -->
    <tr>
      <td value="2">2</td>
      <td>Clark</td>
      <td>Kent</td>
    </tr>
    <!-- Datarow 3 -->
    <tr>
      <td value="3">3</td>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Romero</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is good, but if I understand correctly it will only show index od the row, and I need to check what is inside the row sth like: record_id = rowIdx.first_td.value. I gues I could use js for this, but again it would be broken by paging so I need to use datatable api.

Comment: Thx, sorry you had to wait for me to anwear (job). this works fine: alert('data:' + this.data()[0]); but the === is not working for some reason. I try to figure this out now.

Comment: Figured out :P == instead of === `if (this.data()[0] == 10) { alert('data:' + this.data()[0]); }`. Could you please correct this so I could accept you answear? Thans for help.

Comment: You could still actually use the tertiary operator (===), although the data type of the two variables you are comparing should be the same. The data type of the return of `this.data()[0]` is **string** so, the right variable should also be a string ("10"). Finally, the code should look like `if (this.data()[0] === "10")`. Sorry for the late reply. Accept the answer if this answered your question. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes. Thanx for help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do all the tedious HTML handwritting, you may source your table using javascript object (that's what I did in the following example).

You're right, there is an embedded iterator over DataTables rows, it is [`every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) method.

What you need to do is, basically, grab necessary record, modify it, [`rows().remove()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().remove()) old record, [`row.add()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) the new one and do re-`draw()`.

Here is the **DEMO**:

```js
//Define source data
var dataSrc = [
  {id:1, name: 'John', lastname: 'Wayne'},
  {id:2, name: 'Clark', lastname: 'Kent'},
  {id:3, name: 'John', lastname: 'Romero'},
];
//Define DataTable object
var dataTable = $('#data_tables').DataTable({
  sDom: 't',
  data: dataSrc,
  columns: [
    {title: 'id', data: 'id'},
    {title: 'name', data: 'name'},
    {title: 'lastname', data: 'lastname'},
  ]
});
//Create dynamically interface for editing
$('body').append(`
<div id="editingform" style="display:none">
  <select id="idselector">
    <option value="" disabled selected>id</option>
  </select>
</div>
`);
//Append fields that correspond to table columns minus id column
dataTable.columns().every(function(){
  if(this.dataSrc() == 'id') return;
  $('#editingform').append(`
    <input class="fieldsinput" datasrc="${this.dataSrc()}" placeholder="${this.dataSrc()}"></input>
  `);
});
//Populate id select with possible options
$.each(dataTable.column(0).data(), function(index, value){
  $('#idselector').append(`
    <option value="${value}">${value}</option>
  `);
});
//Append 'Edit' button and make editing form visible
$('#editingform').append(`<button id="editbutton">Edit</button>`);
$('#editingform').show();
//Listen for id selection and populate input fields
$('#idselector').on('change', function(){
  //Grab row with matching 'id' value
  let rowData = dataTable.rows(`:has(td:eq(0):contains('${$(this).val()}'))`).data()[0];
  //Update input fields
  $.each(rowData, function(index, value){
    $(`input[datasrc="${index}"]`).val(value);
  });
})
//Change source data upon 'Edit' button click and redraw dataTable
$('#editbutton').on('click', function(){
 //Prepare new entry
 let newEntry = {id:$('#idselector').val()};
 $.each($('.fieldsinput'), function(){
  newEntry[$(this).attr('datasrc')] = $(this).val();
 });
 //Remove corresponding column, add new and redraw
 dataTable.rows(`:has(td:eq(0):contains("${newEntry.id}"))`).remove();
 dataTable.row.add(newEntry);
 dataTable.draw();
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<table id="data_tables"></table>
</body>
```

Comment: Wow. This is nice! Unfortunatelly in project I work on now data handling is run from php level, so it looks like this: iframe inside webpage is handling adding/editing new record, and I plan to insert new record into datatable (I have this working already). Now I need to create js function (call as parent from child iframe) that will edit row that is already there (I know - sound complicated, but I inherited this project) :D

Comment: What I mean is: this must be working with php, but without reloading page and datatables (save filtering and so on). I know there is an option to store datatables filter in session, but it doesn't work to well. Sorry for poor english.

Comment: I've answered your question exactly as it was stated. In order to get your **real** problem solved, you might need to describe the **actual** environment and your **real** expectations.

Comment: Ekown's answer works for me just fine. Your solution is good, someone might use it.